# Logstash don't read my log file

Tags: logstash

I'm trying to configure logstash to use with elasticsearch but i can't read my log files.

The pattern of my log is:

```
 17:06:08.915 TKD [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1] INFO  
                                 javax.mail - Tables of loaded providers
 17:10:53.767 TKD [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-6] INFO  application - Starting
                                 Jobing [company.Job]
```

How can i configure it to get [Datetime] [TKD] [DefaultQuartzScheduler] [Level] [app] [Message]?

Where my fields could be filled like this:

[DateTime] = 17:06:08.915

[TKD] = TKD

[DefaultQuartzScheduler] = DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1

[Level] = INFO

[app] = javax.mail

[Message] = Tables of loaded providers

Here is my conf file:

```
input {
    file {
        add_field => [ 'host', 'my-dev-host' ]
        path => 'c:\tmp\utracking.log'
        type => 'app'
        format => 'plain'
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch_http {
        host => 'localhost'
        port => 9200 
        type => 'app'
        flush_size => 10
    }
}

filter {
    multiline {
        type => 'app'
        pattern => '^[^\[]'
        what => 'previous'  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [grok](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/grok) filter is what you are looking for, if you want to extract fields from your message that you can then manipulate and send to output. You can find a list of grok patterns [here](https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns). The grok link gives some pretty good examples, so I'll just leave it at that.

Keep in mind that you'll want to put your grok filter after your multiline filter.

I hope this helped!